# Slide in replace body

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get an animation right.

What i am doing is, on clicking a button, load another page by AJAX.

The page is succesfully loaded and the body is replaced with the body of the other page.

```
$("#csubmit").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "body.html",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(html) {
            $('body').html(html);
        }
    });
    return false ;
});
```

However, i want an effect with this, like the new content should slide up / down to replace the body.

Is there an easy way to do this, maybe a jquery plugin is already available?

Comment: show main element structure of parents of the new html. Is it a full page with head/body etc? Or just some block elements?

Comment: Just some block elements.

Comment: can do sevral things...depends on what you want...show message while loading ( or loading GIF) or just hide body and slide when new content arrives...or as solutions below...show same content and hide it when new content arrrives and slide it then

Comment: This is what i want to do. Check this website: http://teamgeek.co.za

Click on the icons from the "Some cool stuff we've made" and check the sliding effect.

Comment: their content is already in the page...and page is a lot more advanced than just replacing body content.. so not sure what your overall goal is. Start by looking at link @Hristo gave you and work from there. Also lots of  single page layout plugins available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supported out of the box - http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/